# Enumeration of all possible samples with replacement

Tags: matlab, sample

I would like to write a fast efficient code to enumerate all possible samples with replacement. That is, I need a bijective function between the set of all samples of length  `k` taken from a set of n elements A = `{a_1,...,a_n}`, that is A x A ...x A (k times), and the subset of natural numbers {1,2,..,n^k} fast to compute in Matlab.

For now I am generating an array M of all such samples in their rows  and then, for every given sample S, I am checking which is the corresponding row with function

```
    ismember(S,M,'rows')
```

but this is not very efficient. Any help on how to speed up this procedure?

Comment: What is the range of `n`? I'm assuming if you're generating all of the samples that it's reasonable and `n^k` will fit in a double?

Comment: 'n' is small, n<=10, and also 'k' is of same order

Comment: In that case, this seems to me to be a base conversion from base-n to base-10, correct?

Comment: Or have I misunderstood the question?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't had the possibility to connect last two days, I am thinking now to your suggestion.

Comment: Ok, your suggestion is good, if you want to post it as an answer I will close this question. And, btw, if you have time, you may give a look to the specific question on how to implement it in Matlab which I posted here:
https://it.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/475214-enumeration-of-all-possible-samples-with-replacement-trough-base-conversion

Comment: The inverse of `base2dec` is `dec2base`. I'm not sure what you need beyond that. If you can come up with a concrete example of where that does not work, I'll be glad to have a look at it.